# Does this sequence have a limit or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$ \lim \limits_{n \to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{3n}{2n^2 + 3}\right) \sin\left(\frac{2n^2 + 3}{3n}\right) $$
Does this become  $$ \lim \limits_{n \to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{3n}{2n^2 + 3}\right) \times \lim \limits_{n \to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{2n^2 + 3}{3n}\right) = 0 \times \infty  $$  which is indeterminate form ??

Comment: **Hint** $|\sin(1/n)\sin(n)|\leq |\sin(1/n)|$.

Comment: @Surb Do you mean to use the squeezing theorem?

Comment: what do you think ? ;-)

Comment: @Surb I believe yes, and the limit will equal to 0 but I do not understand where I made a mistake in my solution

Comment: You can separate lim ab =lim a lim b only when both limits exists finitely.

Comment: The second limit is not $\infty$, but $\sin(\infty)$.

Comment: $\sin((2n^2+3)/(3n))$ doesn't have a limit of $\infty$, it is always between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Andrei There is no such thing as $\sin(\infty)$.  $\sin(2n^2+3)/(3n))$ doesn't have a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: It is not $0\times\infty$ form.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Correct. It does not have a limit, but it's bounded between $-1$ and $1$. So it's not $\infty$, therefore the product is not of the type $0\cdot\infty$

Answer (score 1):

By
$$ |\sin x|\le |x|, |\sin x|\le 1$$
one has
$$ \bigg|\sin\left(\frac{3n}{2n^2 + 3}\right) \sin\left(\frac{2n^2 + 3}{3n}\right)\bigg|\le \frac{3n}{2n^2 + 3}. $$
Since
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{2n^2 + 3}=0$$
one has
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{3n}{2n^2 + 3}\right) \sin\left(\frac{2n^2 + 3}{3n}\right)=0.$$